# Имеет ли смысл очищать форму в WF перед её закрытием?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

**Имеет ли смысл очищать саму форму во время её закрытия?**

Например, у меня есть форма с таблицей, данные которой постоянно обновляются. Так вот, когда я закрываю форму - стоит ли очищать эту таблицу перед закрытием или нет?

Comment: Что подразумевается под закрытием: `Hide()` или `Close()`? Все _неуправляемые_ ресурсы хорошо бы диспозить. С управляемыми можно особо ничего не делать, если только ссылки на них не удерживаются (это приведёт к утечке памяти).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, под закрытие понимаю событие, которое срабатывает после нажатия кнопки крестика на форме (*.FormClosed).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, все неуправляемые ресурсы я сразу освобождаю или закрываю, после их выполнения.